# Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but notes has 1.'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Browser Console : Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but notes has 1.

```
async function updateNote(text) {
    const docRef = doc(db, "notes", currentNoteId)
    await setDoc(
        docRef, 
        { body: text, updatedAt: Date.now() }, 
        { merge: true }
    )
}
```

I am trying to delete a note from my local array of objects as well s from the firebase. I am a beginner and unable to resolve the problem.

Comment: This is probably due to the fact that `currentNoteId` is `undefined` or `null`. Is `currentNoteId` defined in a larger scope than the `updateNote` function? Can you log it?